# Coding the number of visits based on dates and assigning value in new column R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, group-by, dplyr

I am relatively new to R and am trying to create a new column for number of visits (ie num_visits) based on the admission dates (ie admit_date)

The sample dataframe is below and the number of visits has to be created based on the admit_date column. The admit_dates do not necessarily run in sequence.

```
subject_id     admit_date        num_visits
22             2010-10-20        1
23             2010-10-20        1
24             2010-10-21        1
25             2010-10-21        1
22             2010-12-30        3
22             2010-12-22        2
23             2010-12-25        2
30             2011-01-14        1
31             2011-01-14        1
33             2011-02-05        2
33             2011-01-26        1
```

I know i need to groupby subject_id and perhaps get the counts based on the sequence of the dates.

Am stuck after the following codes, appreciate any form of help, thank you!

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate` after grouping by 'subject_id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(subject_id, as.Date(admit_date)) %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  mutate(num_visits = row_number())
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(as.IDate(admit_date)), num_visits := rowid(subject_id)][]
#    subject_id admit_date num_visits
# 1:         22 2010-10-20          1
# 2:         23 2010-10-20          1
# 3:         24 2010-10-21          1
# 4:         25 2010-10-21          1
# 5:         22 2010-12-30          3
# 6:         22 2010-12-22          2
# 7:         23 2010-12-25          2
# 8:         30 2011-01-14          1
# 9:         31 2011-01-14          1
#10:         33 2011-02-05          2
#11:         33 2011-01-26          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(subject_id = c(22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
30L, 31L, 33L, 33L), admit_date = c("2010-10-20", "2010-10-20", 
"2010-10-21", "2010-10-21", "2010-12-30", "2010-12-22", "2010-12-25", 
"2011-01-14", "2011-01-14", "2011-02-05", "2011-01-26")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you. Will this work even if the dates do not run in sequence?

Comment: @wjie08 yes, it would work because we are grouping by 'admit_date' as well

Comment: can't seem to work, i need to create a new column called num_visits with the count of the number of visits based on admission dates

Comment: @wjie08 can you please check now